# Error when build project in new Xcode 8.0 beta

Tags: ios, swift3

Signing for SWRevealViewController requires a development team. Select a development team in the Target Editor.

Code signing is required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
[image]

Comment: did you add developer account in  the Projects -> Targets -> General?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have my developer account configured properly

Comment: I am having the same issue even though I changed the developer account for each pod.

Comment: @anishparajuli I don't see "Projects" in the menu anywhere, you you have screenshot?

Answer (score 30):

I combatted this last night.  I assume you are using Pods:  For each [Pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXuvT.png), [change the Team under Signing (as shown here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSG9l.png)

edit:  Screenshots are in Xcode 8 (now)

Comment: This is not a good solution because you will have to do it every time you run pod install

Comment: @ErikSapir, have you shown this to be true?  I have been doing pod updates and pod installs while going between Xcode 7 and Xcode 8 without an issue.

Comment: @ErikSapir You do not need to do this for every pod. Just do it for the Pod-YourAppName section

Comment: How to get to the screen in the screenshot?

Comment: The one thing I thought Apple had finally gotten working OK, and they completely screw it up again in Xcode 8. What is going on there!?

Comment: I'll also add that after setting the team as shown above, I also had to set the team in Targets > navigatorTests > General > Signing.

Answer (score 8):

I stole this from Anish:

Project tab -> list of Targets -> General tab for the target xcode complains about (in my case that's my framework used by my applications) -> choose your team

My project does not use pods. Sheesh.

UPD: now my project has picked up developers from the brave new world and it does use pods now (sudo hardlyagem install cocoapods), but that's hardly relevant since the solution I stole from Anish predates the import of boatload of 3rd party problems, all alike

Comment: Don't see "Projects" in the menu?

Comment: ahh, let me rewrite

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thank you. I was able to set myself to 'personal team'. Click the project name to see a drop-down of Targets if you are unable to find it initially.

Comment: You didn't steal anything — you copy/pasted from a free, public source.

The word "steal" has too many negative connotations that I do recommend removing it from your everyday vocabulary.

Comment: That was tongue in cheek comment. I had to give the due credit to the guy who started me thinking in an expedient direction anyways. More so that he did not bother to make an answer of his own, merely lurking in the comments to the original question.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by deleting my apple id from Xcode preferences and restarting it . Sign in with your ID again and you'll be good to go

Comment: After doing this, I still have to select a "development team", so this does not answer the OP's problem. The real issue for me is that the team selection is saved in the .pbxproj file. This selection should be saved in xcuserdata not the project as the .pbxproj is in source control and shared with others.

Comment: Thank you inzo. I removed the account  and added it back and the signing area then showed my account

Answer (score 5):

Cocoapods needs to be updated to add in your projects team information. Maybe this new version of Xcode doesn't rely on the active running project for code signing information anymore. This could also be an indication of a bug from the new code signing in Xcode 8.0. I suppose Apple's developers use SPM over Cocoapods (at least that is what they test with). From what I can tell its only a matter of adding in this data to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file

```
TargetAttributes = {
    698A37611B31C6E9B1C5AEC735CECE70 = {
        DevelopmentTeam = XXXXXXXXXX;
        DevelopmentTeamName = My Team Name";
        ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;
    };
    90B2840AB96CFDCBD62C7A56DFD6562C = {
        DevelopmentTeam = XXXXXXXXXX;
        DevelopmentTeamName = "My Team Name";
        ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;
    };
    B07B012AE17952EE777271E277F90284 = {
        DevelopmentTeam = XXXXXXXXXX;
        DevelopmentTeamName = "My Team Name";
        ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;
    };
    B6184234CE5B97D6DADDB68315E67B58 = {
        DevelopmentTeam = XXXXXXXXXX;
        DevelopmentTeamName = "My Team Name";
        ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;
    };
};
```

These target hashes can be found under `/* Begin PBXNativeTarget section */`. So now it just needs to be implemented into Cocoapods.

**UPDATE:**

An issue has been opened on Github so I would just track this until it is resolved: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5523

**UPDATE 2:**

A PR has been created here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/5528. Seems the valid approach is to disable code signing completely for any Pod projects and targets.

To use the above link, since it hasn't been merged as of 6/27/16, the branch that includes this feature is `https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/tree/xcode-8-codesigning`. Just follow the guide here to use this branch https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/unreleased-features.

**UPDATE 3:**

The PR was merged so anybody who has this problem should just update Cocoapods via `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: What are we supposed to do with those links?

Comment: @GoldenJoe The last link is a pull request that shows Cocoapods is aware of this issue and has already fixed it but just has'y merged it into their library. So you can either wait for that PR to be merged or you can use the the branch that already has this feature included. I'll include a little guide to do the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You should install cocoapods beta as they solved that issue on its RC version.
To install `cocoapods beta` simply use the following command in your terminal

```
gem install cocoapods --pre
```

and run pod install again by

```
pod install
```

Your errors should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Click on each project in the navigator and choose a team.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I have deleted the current pod file and remove all the pods from the Xcode project and also it's settings.

Further, I created a `pod` file using the terminal.

1. Open Terminal
2. Navigate to your Project Path
3. Type `pod init` in terminal to create new pod file
4. Open the newly created pod file and write the pod line which you want to install after `target "TargetName" do` and before `end`.
5. Then type `pod install` in the terminal

Then finally I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Select each target in pod and select the team in General tab section 
It resolves the problem

Comment: You would have to do this every time you run pod install or pod update.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the Frameworks folder and it worked
[image]