# Xcode Build Error: Signing for AWSCore requires a development team

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, cocoapods

I was able to run my Swift project on the emulator successfully, but wen I try to run it with the device I'm keep getting this error.

[image]

This is my POD file

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘9.0’
use_frameworks!
target :’safetyv1’ do
    pod 'AWSS3'
end
```

I tried to do the following in both MyProject.xcodeproj and Pods.xcodeproj

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm still getting both errors, I can't run it with my IPhone. I'm using Version 8.0 beta (8S128d) and deployment target set to 8.0 in both .xcodeproj files.

Can someone please help me to fix this? I am stuck with this.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I managed to fix it. I will post my answer here so it will help someone.
Click on the Pods (blue icon) and expand the left navigation under Pods page. This will show you the installed libraries. Click on the targets one by one and assign a team.

[image]

Now you can Clean the project and run it without errors.

This might not the best solution, this is a quick fix to run your project.
More info
[Error when build project in new Xcode 8.0 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807161/error-when-build-project-in-new-xcode-8-0-beta)